# How to find the column names in Ruby Sequel arbitary sql run

Tags: ruby, sequel

I am running an arbitrary sql using Ruby Sequel DB.run. I would like to find out the column names of the dataset.

Is it possible in Ruby Sequel ?

Comment: give the documentation link..

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist(http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you provide a minimal working example (a code example to see what you want and if possible without )?

I'm guessing what you do:

```
require 'sequel'

db = Sequel.sqlite()
db.create_table(:test){
  field :x1
  field :x2
}
db[:test].insert(1,2)
p db.run('select * from test') #->nil
```

If you don't use `run` but `[]` you get another result:

```
p db['select * from test']  #-> #<Sequel::SQLite::Dataset: "select * from test">
```

Based on this solution you can use `columns` to get the fields:

```
p db['select * from test'].columns  #->[:x1, :x2]
p db['select x1 from test'].columns  #->[:x1]
```

Comment: "MWE"? Could you provide a "SUA" (sufficiently understandable acronym)?

Comment: @theTinMan Sorry, jumping between different communities with different wording confused me.

Answer (score 3):

Using Sequel's [basic statup-up example](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/):

```
require "sequel"

# connect to an in-memory database
DB = Sequel.sqlite

# create an items table
DB.create_table :items do
  primary_key :id
  String :name
  Float :price
end

# create a dataset from the items table
items = DB[:items]
```

The [`columns`](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-columns) method will return the fields defined for a particular table:

```
items.columns # => [:id, :name, :price]
```

You can also do it directly using:

```
DB[:items].columns # => [:id, :name, :price]
```